# Banshee will not import media since 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, sync, banshee, ipod

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 on  my AMD64 Desktop which has been happily importing media from my iPod 5th gen into Banshee with no problem all year. After installing 12.04 all Banshee does is remember ipod files and seems to treat it as a drive to play media from, but not import media to PC.

If I click on **Import** all that happens is that the file names get imported with their location on the iPod but no actual files get transferred as used to happen.

Is there a fix for this is should I just wait for a program update ?

Comment: Banshee cannot perform music sync with iOS 5. What you described is similar to what happens with an attempted sync to iOS 5.

Comment: Yes. I have had this problem with Banshee/iPod before after Ubuntu upgrades, then months later after a program update it suddenly works again. I love Banshee but it's really frustrating

Comment: Try to use gtkpod, Banshee internally uses it as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try a re-install something could of got messed up in the upgrade

sudo apt-get remove banshee

then

sudo apt-get install banshee

It might not help but at least you will definitely have the latest version.